# Getting an Uncaught TypeError that is preventing a score alert that I'm unsure how to fix even though my game plays as normal

Tags: javascript, html, typeerror

So with my Yahtzee code, my game plays normally, but I am unable to get my alert for the total score and the alert that you received bonus points. I've discovered where the issues are I'm just unsure as to how to fix it. I tried debugging through alerts and from what I can gather it seems like the dice rolls aren't adding together to make the total unless my assumption is wrong.

[Error I am Receiving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tky7b.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Yahtzee</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style>
........
</style>

<script>
.......
</script>

</head>
<body style="background-color: black;"  onload="getUser()">

<div class="container">

    <header id="pageHeader">
        <h1> <img src="yahtzee.jpg" width="100px"> YAHTZEE </h1>
    </header>

    <ul class="nav nav-pills red">
        <li class="active"><a href="https://usbrandcolors.com/oracle-colors/" target="_blank"> Color Scheme </a></li>
    </ul>
    <br>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm">
                <table>
                    <br>
                    <span style="color: white"> Player Name: </span>
                    <span style="color: white" id="player"> </span>
                    <br>
                    <span style="color:white;"> <strong> SCORE BOARD </strong> </span>
                    <br>
                    <tr>
                        <th> Win Points </th>
                        <th>   200</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>  Wins </td>
                        <td>   0 </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> Losses  </td>
                        <td>   0 </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <table class="table table-bordered border-dark border border-2 table-md">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Upper Section</th>
                        <th>How to Score</th>
                        <th>Game #1</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>  ACE <img src="Die1.PNG" width="45px"> = 1 </td>
                        <td> COUNT AND ADD ONLY ACES </td>
                        <td><div id="aces1"></div></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> TWOS <img src="Die2.PNG" width="45px"> = 2  </td>
                        <td> COUNT AND ADD ONLY TWOS </td>
                        <td><div id="twos1"></div></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>  THREES <img src="Die3.PNG" width="45px"> = 3</td>
                        <td> COUNT AND ADD ONLY THREES</td>
                        <td><div id="threes1"></div></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> FOURS <img src="Die4.PNG" width="45px"> = 4 </td>
                        <td> COUNT AND ADD ONLY FOURS </td>
                        <td><div id="fours1"></div></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> FIVES <img src="Die5.PNG" width="45px"> = 5</td>
                        <td>COUNT AND ADD ONLY FIVES</td>
                        <td><div id="fives1"></div></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> SIXES <img src="Die6.PNG" width="45px"> = 6 </td>
                        <td> COUNT AND ADD ONLY SIXES </td>
                        <td><div id="sixes1"></div></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> 3 OF A KIND </td>
                        <td> ADD TOTAL OF ALL DICE </td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> 4 OF A KIND </td>
                        <td> ADD TOTAL OF ALL DICE </td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> FULL HOUSE </td>
                        <td> SCORE 25 </td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="font-size: 30px"> TOTAL SCORE </td>
                        <td> <img src="whitearrow.png" width="100px" > </td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="font-size: 30px"> BONUS w/ total score </td>
                        <td style="font-size: 30px"> SCORE 35 </td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="font-size: 30px"> TOTAL </td>
                        <td> <img src="whitearrow.png" width="100px" > </td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div id="yourRoll" class="col-sm">
                <h2 style="color: white"> Your Roll </h2>
                <div id="die1">
                    <img src="Die1.PNG" width="45px">
                </div>
                Die 1 <input type="checkbox" name="options" id="cdie1" />
                <div id="die2">
                    <img src="Die2.PNG" width="45px">
                </div>
                Die 2 <input type="checkbox" name="options" id="cdie2" />
                <div id="die3">
                    <img src="Die3.PNG" width="45px">
                </div>
                Die 3 <input type="checkbox" name="options" id="cdie3" />
                <div id="die4">
                    <img src="Die4.PNG" width="45px">
                </div>
                Die 4 <input type="checkbox" name="options" id="cdie4" />
                <div id="die5">
                    <img src="Die5.PNG" width="45px">
                </div>
                Die 5 <input type="checkbox" name="options" id="cdie5" />
                <div id="die6">
                    <img src="Die6.PNG" width="45px">
                </div>
                Die 6 <input type="checkbox" name="options" id="cdie6" />
                <br>
                <div>
                    </br>
                    <p> Rolls Left: <span id="rollsRem"> 2 </span> Turns Left: <span id='turnsLeft'> 5 </span> </p>
                    </br>
                    <button  type="button" id="rollbutt" onclick="roll();" style="color: black"> Roll Button </button>
                    </br>
                    <button style="color: black" type="button" id="reset"> Reset </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

```
        body {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-areas:
            "header";
        }

        #pageHeader {
            grid-area: header;
        }

        header {
            background: black;
        }

        header h1 {
            font-family: Verdana;
            font-size: 32px;
            color: white;
        }

        .nav-pills > li.active > a, .nav-pills > li.active > a:focus {
            color: black;
            background-color: #f80000;
        }

        .nav-pills > li.active > a:hover {
            background-color: #f80000;
            color:black;
        }

        th, td {
            border-style:solid;
            border-color: white;
            font-family: "Arial Rounded MT Bold";
            font-weight: bolder;
            border-width: 2px;
            color: white;
        }

        #scoreCard {
            right: 500px;
            top: 150px;
            border-style:solid;
            border-color: black;
            font-family: "Arial Rounded MT Bold";
            font-weight: bolder;
            width: 300px;
        }

        #yourRoll {
            color: white;
        }

        div h2 img {
            color: white;
            float: right;
            padding-right: 150px;
        }
```

```
        let dice = [
            {'img':"Die1.PNG", 'value': 1},
            {'img':"Die2.PNG", 'value': 2},
            {'img':"Die3.PNG", 'value': 3},
            {'img':"Die4.PNG", 'value': 4},
            {'img':"Die5.PNG", 'value': 5},
            {'img':"Die6.PNG", 'value': 6}
        ]

        let checkedDice = [
            {'dice':0, 'checked': false, 'id' : "die1"},
            {'dice':0, 'checked': false, 'id' : "die2"},
            {'dice':0, 'checked': false, 'id' : "die3"},
            {'dice':0, 'checked': false, 'id' : "die4"},
            {'dice':0, 'checked': false, 'id' : "die5"},
            {'dice':0, 'checked': false, 'id' : "die6"},
        ]

        let scoreCard = [
            {'num' : 1, 'value' : 0, 'area' : "aces1"},
            {'num' : 2, 'value' : 0, 'area' : "twos1"},
            {'num' : 3, 'value' : 0, 'area' : "threes1"},
            {'num' : 4, 'value' : 0, 'area' : "fours1"},
            {'num' : 5, 'value' : 0, 'area' : "fives1"},
            {'num' : 6, 'value' : 0, 'area' : "sixes1"},
        ]

        var turns = 5;
        var savedValue = 0;
        var keeper = 0;
        var rollsRem = 3;
        var wins =0;
        var losses = 0;
        const winPoints = 200;

        function getUser()
        {
            document.getElementById("player").innerHTML = prompt(" Please Enter your name: ");
        }


        // Function that will roll dice
        function roll() {
            if (rollsRem > 0) {

                for (let i = 0; i < checkedDice.length; i++) {
                    if (checkedDice[i].checked == false) {
                        let rollDice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
                        document.getElementById(checkedDice[i].id).innerHTML = `<img src="${dice[rollDice].img}" width='45px'>`;
                        checkedDice[i].value = dice[rollDice].value;
                    }
                }
                rollsRem--;
                var display = document.getElementById("rollsRem");
                display.innerHTML = rollsRem;
            } else {
                nextRound();
                for(let j = 0; j < checkedDice.length; j++)
                {
                    checkedDice[j].checked = false;
                    //rollsRem = 4;
                }
            }
        }

        $( document ).ready(function() {
            reset();

            function reset() {
                roll();
            }

            $("#reset").click(function () {
                alert("reset this");
                rollsRem = 3;
                var display = document.getElementById("rollsRem");
                display.innerHTML = rollsRem;
                roll();
                $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function () {
                    $(this).prop('checked', false);
                });

                $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function () {
                    $(this).prop('value', 0);
                });
                turns--;
                document.getElementById("turnsLeft").innerHTML = `${turns}`;

            })

            $("#cdie1").click(function () {
                if (checkedDice[0].checked) {
                   checkedDice[0].checked = false;
                 } else {
                   checkedDice[0].checked = true;
                 }
            })
            $("#cdie2").click(function () {
                if (checkedDice[1].checked) {
                    checkedDice[1].checked = false;
                } else {
                    checkedDice[1].checked = true;
                }
            })
            $("#cdie3").click(function () {
                if (checkedDice[2].checked) {
                    checkedDice[2].checked = false;
                } else {
                    checkedDice[2].checked = true;
                }
            })
            $("#cdie4").click(function () {
                if (checkedDice[3].checked) {
                    checkedDice[3].checked = false;
                } else {
                    checkedDice[3].checked = true;
                }
            })
            $("#cdie5").click(function () {
                if (checkedDice[4].checked) {
                    checkedDice[4].checked = false;
                } else {
                    checkedDice[4].checked = true;
                }
            })
            $("#cdie6").click(function () {
                if (checkedDice[5].checked) {
                    checkedDice[5].checked = false;
                } else {
                    checkedDice[5].checked = true;
                }
            })
        });

        // Adds points into the scorecard, provides total score, as well as enters the next turn
        // function nextRound() {
        //     let keeper;
        //     let sumRound = 0;
        //     let totalSum = 0;
        //     let bonus = 35;
        //
        //     if (turns > 0) {
        //
        //         keeper = prompt("Which Numbers Would You Want to keep?: ")
        //
        //         for (let i = 0; i < checkedDice.length; i++) {
        //             if (checkedDice[i].value == keeper) {
        //                 sumRound += checkedDice[i].value
        //             }
        //         }
        //         scoreCard[keeper - 1].value = sumRound;
        //
        //         document.getElementById(scoreCard[keeper - 1].area).innerHTML = sumRound.toString();
        //        // alert("Did it make it here?")
        //
        //     } else {
        //        // alert("In the else?")
        //         keeper = prompt("Choose which die to keep ");
        //
        //         for(let i = 0; i < checkedDice.length; i++){
        //             if(checkedDice[i].value == keeper){
        //                 sumRound += checkedDice[i].value;
        //             }
        //     }
        //         //alert("around here?")
        //         scoreCard[keeper-1].value = sumRound;
        //         document.getElementById(scoreCard[keeper-1].area).innerHTML = sumRound.toString();
        //
        //         for(let j = 0; j < checkedDice.length+1; j++){
        //              //alert("maybe here?")
        //             totalSum += scoreCard[j].value;
        //         }
        //
        //         document.getElementById("sum1").innerHTML = totalSum.toString();
        //       //  alert("Here?")
        //         if(totalSum > 62){
        //             totalSum += bonus;
        //             alert("You get a bonus for more than 63 points!")
        //             document.getElementById("bonus1").innerHTML = bonus.toString();
        //             document.getElementById("sum1").innerHTML = totalSum.toString();
        //         }
        //         else {
        //            document.getElementById("bonus1").innerHTML = "0";
        //         }
        //
        //         alert("Game Over. Score is " + totalSum)
        //
        //     }
        // }

        function nextRound(){
            let keep = 0;
            let totalSum= 0;
            let roundSum = 0;
            let bonus = 35;
            if (turns > 0) {
                keep = prompt("What number do you wish to keep? ");
                for (let i = 0; i < checkedDice.length; i++) {
                    if (checkedDice[i].value == keep) {
                        roundSum += checkedDice[i].value
                    }
                }
                scoreCard[keep - 1].value = roundSum;

                document.getElementById(scoreCard[keep - 1].area).innerHTML = roundSum.toString();
            }
            else
            {
                keep = prompt("What number do you wish to keep? ");
                for (let i = 0; i < checkedDice.length; i++) {
                    if (checkedDice[i].value == keep) {
                        roundSum += checkedDice[i].value
                    }
                }
                scoreCard[keep - 1].value = roundSum;

                document.getElementById(scoreCard[keep - 1].area).innerHTML = roundSum.toString();

                for (let j = 0; j < checkedDice.length + 1; j++)
                {
                    totalSum += scoreCard[j].value;
                }
                document.getElementById("total1").innerHTML = totalSum.toString();

                if (totalSum > 62)
                {
                    totalSum += bonus;
                    alert("You get a bonus!!")
                    document.getElementById("bonus1").innerHTML = bonus.toString();
                    document.getElementById("total1").innerHTML = totalSum.toString();

                }
                else
                {
                    document.getElementById("bonus1").innerHTML = "0";
                }
                alert("Game is over. You achieved a score of " + totalSum + "!");
                alert("game over")
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is the error? Please [edit] your question and provide a [mre] along with your _desired_ results, your _actual_ results, including all _errors_, and demonstrate _your research and your attempts_ and explain what precisely didn’t work.

Comment: Copy and paste error messages instead of screenshotting them.

Answer (score 0):

This is your definition/initialization for the checkedDice array

```
let checkedDice = [
   {'dice':0, 'checked': false, 'id' : "die1"},
   {'dice':0, 'checked': false, 'id' : "die2"},
   {'dice':0, 'checked': false, 'id' : "die3"},
   {'dice':0, 'checked': false, 'id' : "die4"},
   {'dice':0, 'checked': false, 'id' : "die5"},
   {'dice':0, 'checked': false, 'id' : "die6"},
]
```

Notice that none of the objects in the array has a "value" property

The only place I see that the value property can be created/set is in the roll function

```
if (checkedDice[i].checked == false) {
    let rollDice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    document.getElementById(checkedDice[i].id).innerHTML = `<img src="${dice[rollDice].img}" width='45px'>`;
    checkedDice[i].value = dice[rollDice].value;
}
```

But, its theoretically possible to have object that never gets a value property added beacuse in that function, the line that sets the .value property is buried within an IF block.  So, if whenever roll runs there is an object in checkedDice that has never had .checked == false, then that object never gets a .value property created and you end up getting the typeof error because that property is undefined when you try to reference it in later IF statements

Easy fix is to add the value property with an initial value to each object in the checkedDice array when it is initialized.